# How do to manual layout in NSView?

Tags: cocoa, layout, nsview, appkit

In `UIView` I can do manual layout by overriding `-layoutSubviews` and `-sizeThatFits:`. This works fine when embedded in auto layout containers, etc. What is the equivalent for `NSView`?

`-layout` and `-fittingSize` are the obvious choices, but the documentation suggests that those are auto layout specific.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for `layout` says:

"Override this method if your custom view needs to perform custom layout not expressible using the constraint-based layout system. In this case you are responsible for setting needsLayout to true when something that impacts your custom layout changes."

Sounds to me like it's what you need.